# pandas_datareader error at getting stock splits from Yahoo

Tags: string, yahoo-finance, stock, datareader, pandas-datareader

I am trying to get stock market data from Yahoo.
I have no problem getting stock price and dividends, but once splits are involved I get errors.

example the "coca cola" stock ('KO')

```
from pandas_datareader import data

start_date = '2000-01-01'
end_date = '2020-12-31'

a = data.DataReader('KO', 'yahoo-actions', start_date, end_date)
```

I get a error (i think referring to a 2:1 stock split):

```
File "<string>", line 1
    2:1
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I run the same code on a stock with no splits (i.e. 'TSLA') it runs without a problem.
I tried making it in to a string but without success.

I am out of ideas and couldn't find a similar question online.
does any one have a idea what might be wrong?

Comment: You could try a package called [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery), specifically the history method on the Ticket class.  The resulting data frame will contain stock splits (if there are any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

In file 'daily.py' in the 'pandas_datareader' lib I changed:

`if "SPLIT" in types:
  def split_ratio(row):
    if float(row["Numerator"]) > 0:
      return eval(row["Splitratio"])
    else:
      return 1`

to:

`if "SPLIT" in types:
  def split_ratio(row):
    if float(row["Numerator"]) > 0:
      return row["Splitratio"] 
    else:
      return 1`

now it works locally but i cant use it on colab.

good enough for now.